# Testing base code with wasm-pack test throws "use of undeclared crate or module" error

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, wasm-bindgen

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here ? I've written script entries in *package.json*, which one for tests looks like this

`"test:headless": "cross-env RUSTFLAGS=\"-C target-feature=+atomics,+bulk-memory,+mutable-globals,+simd128\" rustup run nightly-2022-04-07 wasm-pack test --headless --chrome -- -Z build-std=panic_abort,std",`
altought executed test cannot recognize *wasm-rayon* namespace which is my base code.

here is code to repo: https://github.com/MalwareX95/wasm-playground

[image]

Comment: Don't put text as images.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add rlib in crate-type: https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-pack/tutorials/npm-browser-packages/template-deep-dive/cargo-toml.html

> We also specify `crate-type = ["rlib"]` to ensure that our library can be unit tested with `wasm-pack test`.